# How can I get only records with a unique property using entity framework and linq?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

```
public class Person
{
     public string firstName;
     public string lastName;
}
```

I want a list of all Persons with a unique first name.

Persons table

```
Tom Haverford
Tom Baker
Amy Pond
Amy Santiago
Trish Walker
Chidi Anagonye
```

The query should return

```
Trish, Chidi
```

I've tried using Distinct and a combination of GroupBy and Select, but those return `Trish, Chidi, Tom, Amy`.

Comment: Please show your attempt. GroupBy has a Count property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo on  dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/amICaA)

You can `Group by` then `count` number of duplicated items. After that, you can get the item with `count` value equals to 1 like below.

```
    var arr = new []
    {
        new Person {    firstName = "Tom", lastName = "Haverford" },
        new Person {    firstName = "Tom", lastName = "Baker"},
        new Person {    firstName = "Amy", lastName = "Pond" },
        new Person {    firstName = "Amy", lastName = "Santiago"},
        new Person {    firstName = "Trish", lastName = "Walker"},
        new Person {    firstName = "Chidi", lastName ="Anagonye" }
    };

    var result = arr.GroupBy(p => p.firstName).Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count()});
    foreach(var item in result.Where(p => p.Count == 1))
      Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
```

**Output**

```
Trish
Chidi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by and count functionality together for this :

**1. Get a list of all persons from DB :**

```
var personList = (from p in db.Person select p).ToList(); // I assumed here that your db obj name is 'db' and table name is 'Person'
```

**2. Now apply group by query to get the count of first names :**

```
var q = from x in personList
    group x by x.firstName into g
    let count = g.Count()
    select new {Count = count, Name = g.First().firstName };
```

**3. Now you can get your final result like this :**

```
var finalResult = (from p in q where p.Count == 1 select p).ToList();
```

**Happy Coding...**

Comment: How does it differ from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60091128/9071943)?